# Using ng-include With IIS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iis

The following ng-include tag works on a developer box, but not in an IIS website, because it does not include the site's name in the output.

```
<div ng-include="'/app/feature/list.html'" />
```

On a developer machine running IISExpress this builds a url: http://localhost:49716/app/feature/list.html and works well.

When deployed to IIS the url is: http://server/app/feature/list.html. This does not work because the site is given a name and served at /site. The expected url is http://server/site/app/feature/list.html. This results in a 404 and a broken site.

Shouldn't angular be able to build the true path relative to the site itself? Is there a way to make angular do that without resorting to injecting it as configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was the slash at the from the url. The slash implies an absolute path instead of a relative one. This ng-include works:

```
<div ng-include="'app/feature/list.html'" />
```